# How to refer to the search value in the second parameter of the JavaScript string replace(...) method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a procedure that takes a string and replaces all instances of `url` expressions and surrounds them with `[url][/url]` tags.

For instance,

`"I love StackOverflow.com so much"` ----> `"I love [url]StackOverflow.com[/url] so much"`

Now, the regular expression I'll need is

```
var urlreg = new RegExp("^([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");
```

and I want to replace all instances of those in the string `str`. So I know I'll need to do something like

str.replace(urlreg, ...)

but I'm not sure what to put in place of `...` . W3Schools says I need to put `newvalue` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), but I'm not sure how to refer to the oldvalue so I can do `"[url]" + oldvalue + "[/url]"`.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: that regex doesn't even work, if it did you would have to use `str.match` and capture the URL, then use `replace` with the old value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is **not** meant to give you the best *regular expression* but of how to do the string replacement.

```
var str = 'I love StackOverflow.com so much.',
    rgx = /([^\s]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/,
    res = str.replace(rgx, '[url]$1[/url]')

console.log(res); //=> "I love [url]StackOverflow.com[/url] so much."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert matched substring using `$`:

```
str.replace(urlreg, "[url]$1[/url]");
```